How to reduce timing for the following VB code
For i = 1 To 200
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets("Change Add Remove Contact Info").Range("B2").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Working").Range("A1")
Sheets("Change Add Remove Contact Info").Range("C7").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Working").Range("B1")
Sheets("Change Add Remove Contact Info").Range("C10").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Working").Range("C1")
Sheets("Change Add Remove Contact Info").Range("C11").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Working").Range("D1")
Sheets("Change Add Remove Contact Info").Range("C12").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Working").Range("E1")
Sheets("Change Add Remove Contact Info").Range("C13").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Working").Range("F1")
Sheets("Change Add Remove Contact Info").Range("C14").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Working").Range("G1")
Sheets("Change Add Remove Contact Info").Range("D17").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Working").Range("H1")
Sheets("Change Add Remove Contact Info").Range("C20").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Working").Range("I1")
Sheets("Change Add Remove Contact Info").Range("C21").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Working").Range("J1")
Sheets("Change Add Remove Contact Info").Range("C22").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Working").Range("K1")
Sheets("working").Range("A1:K1").Copy
Sheets("Data").Range("A" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Sheets("Change Add Remove Contact Info").Range("A:F").EntireColumn.Delete
Sheets("Data").Select
Range("A1").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Next i

I am trying to copy paste multiple cells from one FORM to another Spreadsheet. But macro taking huge time to run background.

Just something beside: you didn't change your Application.ScreenUpdating back to True though.

Application.ScreenUpdating = False, Application.DisplayAlerts = False take them out of your loop, you dont need to do it 200 times. Also, have you tried setting calculation to manual? There are like hundred of millions of examples about that.

If you don't need the formatting, you can also just give the values directly, i.e. Sheets("Working").Range("A1").Value = Sheets("Change Add Remove Contact Info").Range("B2").Value. Using worksheet variables would also considerably make this easier to read/write ;)

Why do you copy the same cells  200 times?

@FunThomas Do you mean the Sheets("working").Range("A1:K1").Copy or the other 11 Copy lines? Because OP deletes the first 6 columns each iteration from Sheets("Change Add Remove Contact Info")

I have the customer data in (FORMS/Templates), i am trying to pull the cell info into the list. I used to receive 200+ FORMS. I have created a upstream macro to push all the 200 FORMS into a sheet it took hardly 2 minutes and its added in  ("Change Add Remove Contact Info"). so typically, first 6 columns are "1" form and it goes on until 200 FORMS. Here i am trying to copy required cells into "working" sheet and then copy paste to main sheet "data" in Row (List). post which i am deleting the 1st FORM (1st 6 rows). that is the reason i am adding 200 loop. Let me know it make sense.

I think you should log in to your account you used to post the question, and thank @MGonet for all their hard work and accept their answer.

Try this code:
Sub TestCopy()
    Dim src As Worksheet, dest As Worksheet
    Set src = Sheets("Change Add Remove Contact Info")
    Set dest = Sheets("Data")
    
    Dim A As Variant, rng As Range
    Set rng = src.Range("B2,C7,C10:C14,D17,C20:C22")
    ReDim A(1 To rng.Count)
    
    Dim last As Long
    last = dest.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim B As Variant
    ReDim B(1 To 200)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, c As Range
    For i = 1 To 200
        If i > 1 Then Set rng = rng.Offset(, 6)
        j = 0
        For Each c In rng
            j = j + 1
            A(j) = c.Value
        Next c
        B(i) = A
    Next i
    dest.Range("A" & last + 1).Resize(200, rng.Count) = Application.Index(B, 0)
End Sub


Nifty. I had to read it twice, but it beats what I was going to suggest.
